# Transition probability in time-periodical system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, time-evolution, floquet-theory

There is a derivation of transition probability in Floquet system in the paper ([PHYSICAL REVIEW B85, 184524 (2012)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.184524)).

They considered a time-periodical Hamiltonian $H(t+T)=H(t)$. According to Floquet theory, Floquet state $|\Phi_k(t)\rangle(=|\Phi_k(t+T)\rangle)$ and quasienergy $Q_k$ can be defined. The time-evolutional operator can be written as
$$
F(t,0)=\sum_{k}|\Phi_k(t)\rangle e^{-iQ_k t/\hbar}\langle \Phi_k(0)|.
$$

With this setup, they derived the transition amplitude $P_{\alpha\to\beta}=|\langle\beta|F(t,0)|\alpha\rangle|^2$ as follows:

> The transition probability into the excited state $|\beta\rangle$ ..., averaged over the relative phase, is described by the expression $$
> P_{\alpha \rightarrow \beta}(t)=\sum_{k, l} e^{-i\left(Q_{k}-Q_{l}\right) t / A} \sum_{n} M_{k}^{(n)}(t) M_{l}^{*(n)}(t),\tag{15}
> $$
> where
> $$
> M_{k}^{(n)}(t)=\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} e^{-i n \omega \tau}\left\langle\beta |\Phi_{k}(\tau+t)\right\rangle\left\langle\Phi_{k}(\tau) |\alpha\right\rangle d \tau.\tag{16}
> $$
> ...
> After averaging the expansion for the probability, Eq.(15), by the time interval $t$, we find
> $$
> \bar{P}_{\alpha \rightarrow \beta}=\sum_{k} \sum_{n, n^{\prime}}\left|\langle \beta | \Phi _ { k } ^ { ( n - n ^ { \prime } ) } \rangle \langle\Phi_{k}^{(n)}|\alpha\rangle\right|^{2},\tag{17}
> $$
> where the Fourier components are defined by the relation
> $$
> \left|\Phi_{k}^{(n)}\right\rangle=\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} e^{i n \omega t}\left|\Phi_{k}(t)\right\rangle d t.\tag{18}
> $$

How are $(15)$ and $(17)$ derived?